# can't write and increment the received data in an excel file

Tags: python, xlsx

hello i have a problem reading data and writing it in ".xlsx" file.
i receive data like this ['1.232424,2.3221312,4.3213213,4.2132332,.....'] and i want to import it to excel with each number in his own column but all the data is registred in the first column and it doesn't incremant, here is my code:

```
channels = ["@101:120"]
column = 1
for j in range(len(Sollwerte)):
    for k in channels:

        Dmm.write(':CONFigure:VOLTage:DC %G,(%s)' % (float(Sollwerte[j]), k))
        Dmm.write('ROUT:SCAN '+k)
        Dmm.write('INIT')
        time.sleep(Ts)
        result = Dmm.query('FETCh?')
        time.sleep(Ts)
        data.append(result)
        worksheet.write(j+2, column, result)
        column += 1
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what your spreadsheet looks like? It sounds as if `result` in this line `worksheet.write(j+2, column, result)` is a `list`, and not a single value.

Comment: Thank your for your response, i already found a solution in wich i add a variable for the received Data (result) and separated them with the (' ')  :

            result = Dmm.query('FETCh?')
            vals = result.split(',')

Comment: No worries. You should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for your response, i already found a solution in wich i add a variable for the received Data (result) and separated them with the (' ') :

result = Dmm.query('FETCh?')

vals = result.split(',')